# Why is the average for my array of numbers not correct?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have written a method to take an array (via pointer) and its size to calculate the average. I am still relatively new to pointers. I have tried to remove the reference operator all throughout the code to the point at which it will compile, but the values returning are not intended. For instance, if I pass in an array size of 3, and then my array values are {1, 2, 3}, with my eyes closed I can tell you that that average should be 2. However my code returns 2.666666667. Thinking in reverse, I multiplied 2.6666...7 by 3, which equals 8. This leads me to think that I somewhere, a 2 is getting amended to the array, like {1,2,3,2}, however I'm unsure at this point. If anyone has any experience with pointers/simple arithmetic I'd appreciate your advice, because again, I am new to pointers and this idea of reference by address. Thanks!

```
double *Average(double *arr, int size)
    {
        double *avg;
        avg = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));

        *avg = 0;

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            *avg = *avg + arr[i];
        }

        *avg = *avg / (double) size;

        printf("The average of the array: %f\n", *avg);
        return avg;
}
```

How the method gets called from main:

```
else if (choice == 'C' || choice == 'c')
{
    int count;

    printf("How many numbers do you want to use in the array?\n> ");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    double *arr;
    arr = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * count);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

        printf("Please enter a number (%d of %d)\n> ", i + 1, count);
        scanf("%lf", &arr[i]);
    }

    Min(arr, count);

    Max(arr, count);

    Average(arr, count);
}
```

Tests:

- Average({1,3,5}, 3)

  > Expected: 3, Got: 4.333333
- Average({1,1,1}, 3)

  > Expected: 1, Got: 1
- Average({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, 9)

  > Expected: 5, Got: 5.888889

Two extra methods per user request:

```
double *Min(double *arr, int size)
{
    double *min = &arr[0];
    int i;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < *min)
        {
        *min = arr[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Smallest number in array: %f\n", *min);
    return min;
}

double *Max(double *arr, int size)
{
    double *max = &arr[0];
    int i;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > *max)
        {
            *max = arr[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Largest number in array: %f\n", *max);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Show us how you're calling the function. Not just summaries like `Average({1, 3, 5}, 3)` but actual compilable code. A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, good idea, thanks. It's been added

Comment: Can you edit out the code that's not directly relevant? For instance, hard code the array contents instead of taking in user input. And get rid of the `Min` and `Max` calls. (Note: If doing either of these changes the program behavior then you have a clue.)

Comment: Stepping through the code with a debugger would be extremely useful here.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes I will, but Min and Max are methods that simply print. No manipulation happens in either.

Comment: Your `Average` function would be simpler if it returned a `double` rather than a `double*`. Make `avg` a simple `double` variable. Apart from that, I don't see a problem with your `Average` function, and it works for me. We definitely need a [mcve]. (What you have now is two code fragments. With an MCVE, I could copy-and-paste the entire program onto my system and compile and run it without adding anything.)

Comment: I ran your code with different inputs, it works correctly on my system. gcc on Mac

Comment: @Learner guessing it’s an issue with my GCC then because even after I coded it in such a way that didn’t even use pointers, I was getting some wacky results. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the Min and Max functions as well? I tested out the code you provided and it works fine; the problem really might lie within the other 2 functions

Comment: @Ryolu added the extra code.

Comment: No wonder, you're assigning `min` and `max` the address of your array, and then change them(meaning you're changing your array contents.) I will post the answer.

Comment: @Learner I totally see it now! when I do *min or *max, I totally forgot I'm changing the values at that address. Duh! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: A function that computes an average should compute an average and do nothing else. If you need to print the result, do that in a function that calls Average. This way you get a chance to actually use your return value and free memory you malloc. Same thing about min and max. To make sure you don't inadvertently change the array, use `const double*` parameter type.

Comment: Yes, you're the one asking the question -- and I'm the one telling you what information we need to answer it.  As it turned out, the problem was in code you hadn't shown us. We could have saved a lot of time if you had posted a *complete* program in the first place. For future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here, correct this one:

```
        *max = arr[i];
```

you're changing the `*max` which is `arr[0]` to the max or min of your array. So when `Average()` function gets the array, it's not the array you've input, it's changed. For example:

```
        Max({1,3,5})=5
```

array becomes:

```
        arr={5,3,5}
```

It's average correctly is:

```
       Average({5,3,5} = 4.3333
```